# solr-client-php

Tags: solr, lucene

Can anybody guide me through the integration of solr lucene with Zend. I have a PHP application build using Zend framework. I have installed solr lucene and indexed the mysql database . Now I wants to integrate the solr with the zend. Any help is appreciated ???

Answer (score 0):

I would reference the [SolPHP](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP) page on the Solr Wiki. It details PHP support for Solr and incudes some links to details on how to use different PHP clients for connecting to Solr.

Comment: @Piage: thanks for the link but is there no better link than this. Its confusing :(. Can u provide me with stepwise procedure ??

Comment: Take a look at the solr-php-client site - http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client and you can see a quick start example here - http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/ExampleUsage